# In swagger-editor can I control whether to send an empty parameter or not send the parameter

Tags: swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

Swagger-editor sends optional array parameters even when they are empty. 
Is there a way to specify in Swagger 2.0 to not send the optional parameter if it is an empty array?

The target of the request is intended to be a list of Cats and/or a list of Dogs - neither of which are *required*.

I was hoping that if the request contains only Cats, the caller would only provide a list of Cats, and not have to also send an empty list of Dogs. 
The swagger-editor enforces the empty list.

```
POST http://example:9090/api/testpath HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "Dogs": [
    1
  ],
  "Cats": []
}
```

I am not sure whether this would be a valid request.

```
POST http://example:9090/api/testpath HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "Dogs": [
    1
  ]
}
```

This is an example swagger specification

```
    {
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "title": "demo",
        "version": "Draft 0.1.0"
    },
    "host": "example:9090",
    "schemes": [
        "http",
        "https"
    ],
    "basePath": "/api",
    "produces": [
        "application/json"
    ],
    "paths": {
        "/testpath": {
            "post": {
                "summary": "Request with a complex target\n",
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "target",
                        "in": "body",
                        "required": true,
                        "description": "Array of collars and/or mobs to target with this request.",
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/TargetObjects"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "The request was accepted."
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "TargetObjects": {
            "type": "object",
            "description": "Target of a request may be one or more objects or different types.\n",
            "properties": {
                "Dogs": {
                    "description": "A list of Dogs.",
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "number",
                        "format": "int64"
                    }
                },
                "Cats": {
                    "description": "A list of Pets.",
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "number",
                        "format": "int64"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your Swagger spec?

Comment: I wouldn't do it like this, I would add a kind of animal type field. You have the same fields in each entity, it would make your life easier in some way.

Comment: same question. Trying to implement it in Nestjs for a DTO through @ApiProperty param from decorator